# Why are card security codes always in a certain italic font?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card

I have around 10 different credit + debit cards from different banks, and while they can each have their own font/styling for the 16 digit sequence, all of them have the security code written in this one serif italicized font. Is there a reason for this? I've also noticed that Apple Wallet can't pick up the security codes and always needs me to type them in, are they supposed to be OCR-proof?

Comment: <font style="Goudy"> Is it Helvetica/Arial? Because almost every office document is either in that, or Times.

Comment: I doubt it is OCR-proof. Skipping that block in the OCR is more likely intentional, to abide by the intent of the security code.

Comment: I don’t know, but I have two credit cards and they have different fonts / styles for the security code - neither serif, and one italic and one not. When I scan either card it does pick up the security code as well.

Answer (score 3):

They are not all italic.  Many are because they are one brand or another despite the bank/institution branding.  Most are either Master Card or Visa and those companies have come up with a standard on how to print.

My last AMEX had its security code embossed like the credit card number.

My latest visa has a printed credit card number and the security code is not italic, but actually now bold.  I feel these changes were made for ease of readability and they do help my old eyes.